# Property onAuxClickCapture and onAuxClick is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using `forwardRef` from React gives a weird type error:

```js
Type '{ children: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ILinkProps, "className" | "children" | "accept" | "acceptCharset" | "action" | ... 348 more ... | "onAuxClickCapture">': onAuxClick, onAuxClickCapture
```

It seems that onAuxClick and onAuxClickCapture are somehow being flagged as non-optional.

My type:

```
export interface ILinkProps extends Exclude<keyof HTMLProps<HTMLAnchorElement>, 'href'> {
    state?: TRouteState;
    queryParams?: IQueryObject;
}
```

And the simplified component:

```
const Link = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement, ILinkProps>((props, ref) => {
    const href = getHref()
    return (
        <a {...props} href={href} ref={ref} >
            {children}
        </a>
    )
})

export { Link }
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the issue by updating react and types to the latest version

`npm i react@latest react-dom@latest @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest`